# C program stalls when the serial device's path changes

Tags: c, serial-port, uart

In Linux I am running in the background a program written in C, which periodically communicates with a device connected to one of the USB ports. Although the device is always plugged into the same port, over time it switches from `/dev/ttyACM0` to `/dev/ttyACM1` and back, even when no other devices are connected. Consequently every time a switch occurs, I have to restart the program.

To cope with the problem I have tried [setting up a UDEV rule for a new symlink](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/) and the the symlink works regardless of the changes in the connected device's path. However, when the switch occurs, the program still stalls and needs to be restarted.

Is there a system rule I can implement for the device to keep the same path at all times, or is there another more general approach?

Comment: Run a thread on each path?  Queue up the protocol exchanges and then, hopefully, whichever thread has the link will implement the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

**First approach (easier):** 

If you have access to the other's device code, I would implement a ping message from it. 
Then, I would listen for that ping message, on both tty devices, to see on which port it is received (*/dev/ttyACM0* or */dev/ttyACM1*). 
 
**Second approach:** 

On a separate thread implement an **UDEV** monitor. 
The monitor checks which TTY port is used by your device. 
In case of a port change, just reinit the communication thread...
See [udev_monitor_usb.c](https://github.com/gavv/snippets/blob/master/udev/udev_monitor_usb.c) for a udev monitor usb code.